# Multi-template application in iOS

Tags: ios, templates, user-interface

I am new to iOS development and probably this is really simple question.
So I want to build an application which has a signup screen and after successful login we go to a home screen which is a tabbed application.

How do i achieve this ? I tried searching for this but found all other searches and none that had what i was looking for. Please do not down vote it and any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a UINavigationController (set it as the rootViewController of your window in your app delegate). Initialize the navigation controller with your login view controller. Once the user logs in, just push your `UITabBarController` onto the navigation stack.

Make your root view controller a property of your app delegate so you can easily access it

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *rootNavigationController;

@synthesize rootNavigationController
```

Then in your `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` function:

```
self.rootNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewControler:myLoginViewController]; // assuming myLoginViewController exists

self.window.rootViewController = self.rootNavigationController;
```

Once the user successfully logs in, push the tab bar controller onto the stack.

```
[self.rootNavigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES]; // assuming tabBarController exists
```